# After running the validation code, If I save the file and close it, excel is getting corrupted

Tags: excel, vba

In my excel I have two dropdown options that get the values from the database. Those are names and email IDs. When I try to save the file after the validation code. Excel is getting corrupted when I reopen the file. Can anyone help me with solution?

Thanks in Advance

I used validation vba code. i want to know what changes can help my file not to get corrupted.

Comment: Please share your code (as text).

Comment: When adding Data Validation dropdowns and assigning a string as the source, that string can't be longer than 256 characters.  You won't get any error assigning a longer string, but when the workbook is saved and re-opened you'll get errors.  If you have a lot of values then put them in a range on a (for example) hidden worksheet and link the DV to that range.